# looping through sheets to copy value in a certain range to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm starting to learn my journey in VBA Excel

I have a project to do: to loop through the different sheets in the worksheets 
and copy the value in a specific range in sheets and copy those value to one sheets. How i can achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro for [copying](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.copy) a value from one sheet to another?  You'll also have to cycle through [each](https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/for-each-next-loop/) worksheet in the worksheets collection.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub LoopAndCopy
Dim ws as Worksheet
dim target as worksheet
set target = worksheets("target sheet name goes here") 'sheet you're copying to
For each ws in ThisWorkbook.worksheets  'loop through worksheets
    if ws.name <> target.name then   'if not the target sheet then...
         'copy your range into the next blank row in column A
         ws.range("your range here").copy target.range("A" & rows.count).end(xlup).offset(1,0)
     end if
next ws
```